# process context menu action in qt

Tags: python-2.7, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I manually added the following menu to my QTableWidget.

Here is what I have:

[image]

Part of the code was setup using Qt Designer and I'm modifying it slightly in my code.

Here is the code that I've added to have a context menu:

```
self.group1RegistersTableWidget.addAction(self.actionReadRegister)
self.group1RegistersTableWidget.addAction(self.actionWriteRegister)
self.actionSeparator.setSeparator(True)
self.actionSeparator.setText("")
self.group1RegistersTableWidget.addAction(self.actionSeparator)
self.group1RegistersTableWidget.addAction(self.actionBinRegisterFormat)
self.group1RegistersTableWidget.addAction(self.actionDecRegisterFormat)
self.group1RegistersTableWidget.addAction(self.actionHexRegisterFormat)

self.group2RegistersTableWidget.addAction(self.actionReadRegister)
self.group2RegistersTableWidget.addAction(self.actionWriteRegister)
```

and here is the code that I used

I'm somewhat new to Qt. How do I process these actions. How do I know that Read/Write/Binary/Decimal/Hexadecimal has been clicked. As far as I understand I need to connect some signal to some slot, but I can't figure out which ones. Would someone be able to help me out. I'm using `PyQt4`, but C++ code would also be fine.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `self.actionWhatever.triggered.connect(self.someMethod)`.

Comment: The above code, together with `self.currentItem` (or Cell or Row).